# Cakephp aros table numbers

Tags: cakephp

In cakephp 2 -> Acl -> creation of aros table.

What does it mean the right and left numbers ?

[Image Link](https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/FYT7r47d2rKHm4z9ou5G_zOeDrFKFKLYpW__DTTnR8o?feat=directlink)

ThAnKs.

Comment: duplicate of question [What are the model, lft, and rght fields used in the acos table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705416/what-are-the-model-lft-and-rght-fields-used-in-the-acos-table)

Answer (score 0):

The lft and rght values are an inherent part of the tree structure
(it's a Modified Pre-Order Traversal Tree if you're interested).
Without them, there is no tree structure.

The Acl system can be used to repair a damaged tree based on the
parent_id fields, but without the full left and right stuff, it just
won't be able to do aco or aro lookups, which is pretty fundamental.

I would recommend using the Acl behavior, which implies the Tree
behavior too, as a means of editing these values and having the MPTT
stuff handled for you.

Comment: can be automatically filled or fixed by running console script:
    cake AclExtras.AclExtras recover aro